# How to sum values by month

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to have my spreadsheet to sum up values by month. Note that the dates are not organised chronologically. I've tried the solutions showing here but they are not working for me.
I'm not really good at this.

Here is my document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rEqff3Ce_JRly4S2JJsRQP-QfQKBB9OVF9mYg-1ujl4/pubhtml

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy I added a link to an example, tks!

Answer (score 4):

Please try putting the start and end dates (say in G1 and H1) and a formula such as:

```
=sumifs(C:C,B:B,">="&G1,B:B,"<="&H1)
```

Alternatively, since all your dates appear to be this year, you might extract the month number with something like:

```
=month(B1)
```

copied down to suit and then create a pivot table with that number for Rows.

Comment: I get a parse error. The sheet recognises the date formatting automatically will that influence the results? The Brazilian currency or the DD/MM/YY formats may be a problem? For beginning date I put 01/01/2014 and ending date 31/01/2014, any problems there?

Comment: Im using the Brazilian Custom format. I just enter plain numbers and the sheet updates by itself. The =month(b1) did the job of extracting the months numbers in another column. Maybe I can use this value to group by months. I really use only 1 year in each spreadsheet.

Comment: Something like if month equals 1 sum up, if equals 2 sum up in different cells.

Answer (score 3):

1)   add a helper column which calcluates the month    eg     =date(year(A2),month(A2),1)

2)   Use the **Format > More formats > More date and time formats**    feature to show the helper column as month and year

3)   Use the  **Data > Pivot table report**     feature to make a summary table

Here's a worked example:     https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VIeA4zAjID0y1jo1FnsbfGA4qmpRgAxMykLXi1pOfhc/edit?usp=sharing