# Google Spreadsheets: Sum values for each month

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I would like to sum the values that match each month in a spreadsheet. The spreadsheet looks like this:

```
2015-12-10   15
2015-12-19   10
2016-01-02   15
2016-01-05   25
```

And I want to obtain this:

```
2015-12      25
2016-01      40
```

How can I do that?
I tried to look for a formula like =FOR or =SELECT but there is no such thing in Google Spreadsheets. Looks like I cannot select a range conditionally.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to sum values by month](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/67576/354)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant commands are named [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) and [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en). (There are also [pivot table reports](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=en) that could be used for summarizing data.) The details of implementation vary based on:

1. Whether your date strings like `2015-12-10` are formatted as strings or dates.
2. Whether you want to have 0 for months where no transactions are recorded (if so, then you have to provide the list of months for the summary table manually).

I'll give a version that operates with dates as dates (as they ought to be stored) and outputs data for all months present in the table (so, a month with no records will be absent).

The formula assumes the data is in columns A and B. Its explanation is below.

```
=query(arrayformula({year(A1:A)&"-"&right("0"&month(A1:A),2), B1:B}), "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 order by Col1 asc label Col1 'Month', sum(Col2) 'Total'")
```

#### Preparation

The formula `arrayformula({year(A1:A)&"-"&right("0"&month(A1:A),2), B1:B})` prepares a table for querying. The second column is just your B column. The first column is the month (as text) in format 2016-01. The slightly cumbersome `right("0"&month(A1:A),2)`  is there to get 01 rather than 1 for January.

#### Query

The [query language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) is SQL-like. Here is the query string I used, with linebreaks:

```
select Col1, sum(Col2) 
where Col2 is not null 
group by Col1 
order by Col1 asc 
label Col1 'Month', sum(Col2) 'Total'
```

Here, Col1 and Col2 refer to the columns of the table prepared at the first step. The query selects months and the total for each month, sorting them in order. The labels are optional, inserted just to make the output look better.

#### Remark

If you don't want to have a long formula like that, the preparation step can be a separate formula, creating a helper table, which the `query` command can then refer to.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer! The dates are formatted as a date, not string. I can change the formula to suit my needs.